# MS-SQL 2008 Whole Word Matches

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've spent a few hours researching this and am pretty stumped, probably due to my in-often use of RegEx expressions.

I am looking to match a whole word in either a VARCHAR or TEXT type column in Microsoft SQL 2008.

I have a CLR Assembly [RegEx Function installed](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

I need it to match gun in these sample cases:

- **Gun** Loaded
- Loaded **Gun**
- My **Gun** Is Loaded

and NOT in these cases:

- Guns are great
- I have my guns
- My guns are great

I would rather not go down the full text search route.

Here's some things that I've tried but have failed:

```
WHERE PATINDEX( '%[^a-zA-Z_]' + @keyword + '[^a-zA-Z_]%', name) > 0
```

... doesn't take into account the word at the beginning of the string

```
WHERE name LIKE '%\b' + @keyword + '\b%'
```

... doesn't return anything

```
WHERE name LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + @keyword + '[^A-Za-z]%'
```

... doesn't take into account the word at the beginning of the string

... along with some others I didn't save

I can't seem to rely upon regular expression testers such as http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to get me through this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using your CLR regex function? the examples you have don't look like it.

Comment: I'm grabbing this second hand. I thought the existing code didn't look like it matched the docs. I'll see if I can't understand those docs. Thanks.

Comment: You're not using any CLR function... just the native `LIKE` and `PatIndex` functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to modify `name` to make the comparisons.  Just add a space at the beginning and end, and then you will get all the words.  For instance:

```
WHERE ' '+name+' ' LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + @keyword + '[^A-Za-z]%'
```

should do a pretty good job.

Comment: This will cause problems for strings that are at the maximum length or maximum length minus one. If name is VARCHAR(8000) say and LEN(name) is 7999 then `' ' + name + ' '` will not have a terminating space, if LEN(name) is 8000 then `' ' + name + ' '` will truncate the last character along with not having the terminating space.

Comment: @TT.  If this is actually a problem, then cast the `name` as `varchar(max)`.